# User 'xxxxxxxx' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 2) in cloudcontrolled

Tags: mysql, cloudcontrol

I get this error and need to know how to logon to the database and kill the connections. I am conecting from one computer and don't see how I could have exceeded the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you have the free plan, this allows just few simoultanous connections to the DB. 
You should upgrade the db plan then it will work.